# Cypress cross origin error happens during authentication with firebase, returns back to login page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, cypress, react-admin

I made an admin application with react-admin and I made firebase authentication through react-admin-firebase library. User can both login with username and password, and with google account. I wanted to use login and password while testing as I thought it's gonna be easier to manage when writing tests in cypress. The problem is that when I login, a call to google api is made and that's what triggers the error. This results in cypress not accessing app as an authenticated user but rather returns to login page.

Here's a test I wrote:

```
describe('Login page', () => {
    it('Logged in successfully with login and password', () => {
        cy.visit('http://localhost:3000')

        cy.get('input#username')
            .type('login')
        cy.get('input#password')
            .type('password')
        cy.get('button')
            .contains('Sign in')
            .click()

        cy.visit('/#/users')
    })
})
```

And these are logs that cypress is sending.

[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Or3Cc.png)

Is there any way around it? I tried chromeWebSecurity: false in my config and sadly it didn't help. Thank you in advance.